# Document smears as I scroll in Acrobat Reader DC

Tags: windows-8, pdf, adobe-acrobat, scrolling

Whenever I open a file in Acrobat Reader DC (Windows 8.1), everything starts fine with no errors, except that the document doesn't actually display--it's just a blank white space in the area where the document displays.  If I either (a) click the mouse button in the display area, or (b) switch to another program's window and then back to Reader, the first page displays fine.

So long as I don't scroll.

Once I scroll, the view seems to do what I can only describe as "smearing"--basically, a row or a handful of pixels at some location towards the bottom of the screen simply repeats itself up the screen as I scroll.  Again, once I click in the display area or switch to another program and then back, it displays fine until I scroll again.

If I highlight text with the highlight tool, the highlight itself doesn't actually display except after I do the same (click or switch programs and then back).

I have no clue what's wrong here.  I made no changes that I'm aware of to anything else before this started happening, and uninstalling and reinstalling Reader DC didn't fix the problem.

Interestingly, if I open the PDF in the PDF viewer in Chrome or Firefox, this problem does not happen.

Comment: Have you changed anything in Acrobat's menu View / Preferences?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Do you find any updates to Reader in menu Help > Check for updates ?

Comment: Nope.  I just uninstalled and reinstalled earlier this afternoon to see if that fixed it, so I should have the most current version anyway.

However, in the process of checking that just to be sure, I also noticed that there was a "Repair Installation" entry on the Help menu as well.  I tried that as well, didn't fix it.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with your display card/driver, so please give some information.